# SwiftUI: Navbartitel doesn't move to top when scrolling when I set a background color

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, navbar, background-color

in my current project I want to the set background Color with the following code:

```
NavigationView{
    ZStack{
        Color(color)
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                    VStack(spacing: 250){
                            …
                    }
                 }

                 NavigationLink(destination: TrainingView(übungListVM: übungListVM, daten: daten)){
                    Text("startString")
                        .styleButton()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Workout", displayMode: .automatic)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showSettings.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Settings")
                    
                }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I scroll the Navtitel stays in large font on the top left, but it should move to the top(the normal behaviour). When I comment out "Color(color)" everything works as expected. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is know `NavigationView` behaviour - `List/Form/ScrollView` should be at top to navigation bar display mode changed automatically.

You can play with background of sub-views, like (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

[image: demo]

```
NavigationView{
    ZStack{
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                    VStack(spacing: 250){
                        ForEach(0..<100) {
                            Text("Item \($0)")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(
                        Color.yellow
                    )
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("TrainingView")){
                    Text("startString")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(
                    Color.yellow
                )
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I doesn't work for my case. I can set the background of the scrollview, but I am not able to set the background of the space around the NavigationLink.